# Osmar package in R "Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection"

Tags: r, path, openstreetmap, osmosis, osmar

I am trying to run the osmar package on my windows 10, R 3.4.2, and have correctly installed osmosis. However when I try to run the code:

```
>library("osmar")
>
>src <- osmsource_osmosis(file = "c:/users/ben_c/Documents/FYP/FYP_NL_Map/muenchen.osm", osmosis = "osmosis")
>
>
>nl_bbox <- center_bbox(11.575278, 48.137222, 3000, 3000)
>
>nl <- get_osm(nl_bbox, src)
>
>plot(nl)
```

I get the warning, after osmosis has run:

```
>Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
>In addition: Warning message:
>In file(con, "r") :
>  cannot open file 
>'C:\Users\ben_c\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8YYPkZ\file1b182fca7802': No such file or directory
```

I also get the same error when I run the demo:

```
>demo("navigator")
```

I am relatively new to R so would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: maybe you should delete ‘file’, `src <- osmsource_osmosis("c:/users/ben_c/Documents/FYP/FYP_NL_Map/muenchen.osm", osmosis = "osmosis")`

Comment: Thanks, have just tried that but the same error comes up!

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar error. I could solve the problem by running R (in my case RStudio) as administrator.

I think the problem is that a temp file can't be created.