# How to extract osm data using osmar

Tags: r, windows, osmar

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47137700/5784831) I get an error from `get_osm`

```
library(maptools)
library(osmar)
url <- "http://osmar.r-forge.r-project.org/"
file <- "muenchen.osm.gz"
# download.file(sprintf("%s%s", url, file), file)
# gzip is linux only, on windows I unzipped this manually with 7zip!
# unzip("gzip -d muenchen.osm.gz") 

src <- osmsource_osmosis(file = "140-muenchen.osm")
muc_bbox <- center_bbox(11.575278, 48.137222, 3000, 3000)
muc <- get_osm(x = muc_bbox, source = src)
```

The error is

> Fehler in file(con, "r") : kann Verbindung nicht öffnen Zusätzlich:
>   Warnmeldung: In file(con, "r") :   kann Datei
>   'C:\Users\sqc\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQtndOZ\file3bc03a7b5127' nicht
>   öffnen: No such file or directory

I ran RStudio as administrator, I installed gzip, but it still does not work. Any ideas? I am on windows.

(The example is from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115921/121504))

---

**Edit**:

My path looks like `C:/07 Rprogress/00 Erste Testprogramme/140-muenchen.osm.gz` but I hope this is not the problem

```
file.exists("muenchen.osm.gz")
[1] TRUE
> shell("7z e muenchen.osm.gz")
Der Befehl "7z" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Warnmeldung:
In shell("7z e muenchen.osm.gz") :
  '7z e muenchen.osm.gz' Ausführung mit Fehlerkode 1 fehlgeschlagen
> shell.exec("7z e muenchen.osm.gz")
Fehler in shell.exec("7z e muenchen.osm.gz") : 
  '7z e 140-muenchen.osm.gz' nicht gefunden
> system("7z e muenchen.osm.gz")
[1] 127
```

I follow the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122732/unzip-files-7-zip-via-cmd-command) and set

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\
echo %PATH%
```

**Edit 2**:

```
st_layers("myfile.osm", do_count = TRUE)
Driver: OSM 
Available layers:
        layer_name       geometry_type features fields
1           points               Point       61     10
2            lines         Line String        0      9
3 multilinestrings   Multi Line String        0      4
4    multipolygons       Multi Polygon        0     25
5  other_relations Geometry Collection        0      4
Warnmeldungen:
1: In CPL_get_layers(dsn, options, do_count) :
  GDAL Error 1: Non increasing node id. Use OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO
2: ...
```

Comment: Hi! I don't know how to fix that error with osmar but, if you want, I can provide equivalent code for reading the same .osm data using sf or osmdata package.

Comment: @agila any solution is welcome :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work for reading into R the `muenchen.osm.gz` file.

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
options(width = 120)

# download muenchen.osm.gz file
download.file(
  url = "http://osmar.r-forge.r-project.org/muenchen.osm.gz", 
  destfile = "muenchen.osm.gz", 
  mode = "wb"
)
# Unzip using 7zip. You can also do this manually. 
shell("7z e muenchen.osm.gz")
```

I'm coding now with the `sf` approach. I'm quite sure that it's possible to use `osmdata` to read in R the same `.osm` file but I can't make it work for the moment.

```r
# 1. List all the layers
st_layers("muenchen.osm", do_count = TRUE)
#> Driver: OSM 
#> Available layers:
#>         layer_name       geometry_type features fields
#> 1           points               Point    37583     10
#> 2            lines         Line String    56325      9
#> 3 multilinestrings   Multi Line String       96      4
#> 4    multipolygons       Multi Polygon    32328     25
#> 5  other_relations Geometry Collection      337      4

# 2. Read the lines layer (or any other layer)
muenchen_lines <- read_sf("muenchen.osm", layer = "lines")
```

The printing of the object is quite messy here in SO but it's more clear if you copy and paste the code in R.

```r
# 3. Print the result
muenchen_lines
#> Simple feature collection with 56325 features and 9 fields
#> geometry type:  LINESTRING
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 11.30704 ymin: 48.0155 xmax: 11.82806 ymax: 48.28529
#> geographic CRS: WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 56,325 x 10
#>    osm_id name    highway waterway aerialway barrier man_made z_order other_tags                                geometry
#>    <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   <chr>      <int> <chr>                             <LINESTRING [°]>
#>  1 98     <NA>    tertia~ <NA>     <NA>      <NA>    <NA>           4 "\"junction\"=>\"r~ (11.36604 48.1764, 11.36607 4~
#>  2 99     <NA>    tertia~ <NA>     <NA>      <NA>    <NA>           4 "\"junction\"=>\"r~ (11.36614 48.17414, 11.36617 ~
#>  3 100    <NA>    second~ <NA>     <NA>      <NA>    <NA>           6 "\"junction\"=>\"r~ (11.33037 48.18013, 11.33031 ~
#>  4 101    <NA>    second~ <NA>     <NA>      <NA>    <NA>           6 "\"junction\"=>\"r~ (11.32986 48.18367, 11.32973 ~
#>  5 102    <NA>    primary <NA>     <NA>      <NA>    <NA>           7 "\"junction\"=>\"r~ (11.45455 48.1672, 11.45424 4~
#>  6 680    <NA>    motorw~ <NA>     <NA>      <NA>    <NA>          29 "\"bridge\"=>\"yes~ (11.54136 48.22608, 11.543 48~
#>  7 1939   Gerani~ reside~ <NA>     <NA>      <NA>    <NA>           3  <NA>               (11.48282 48.10904, 11.48291 ~
#>  8 1945   Sonnen~ reside~ <NA>     <NA>      <NA>    <NA>           3  <NA>               (11.48714 48.10564, 11.48732 ~
#>  9 122956 Berber~ reside~ <NA>     <NA>      <NA>    <NA>           3 "\"maxspeed\"=>\"3~ (11.42325 48.15542, 11.42308 ~
#> 10 122957 Otto-K~ reside~ <NA>     <NA>      <NA>    <NA>           3 "\"maxspeed\"=>\"3~ (11.42276 48.15559, 11.42251 ~
#> # ... with 56,315 more rows

# 4. Plot
par(mar = rep(0, 4))
plot(st_geometry(muenchen_lines))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You should also check the [osmdata vignettes](https://docs.ropensci.org/osmdata/articles/index.html) if you want to build your own queries for downloading data from Open Street Map.

## References

If you want to check a few references on `sf` I would suggest reading the [vignettes](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/) (see the Articles) of the package and Chapters 1 to 7 of [Geocomputation with R](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/). If you want to check how to use `osmdata` to create your own queries to Open Street Map I suggest reading the [vignettes](https://docs.ropensci.org/osmdata/articles/index.html). There are a few differences between the two approaches but you can read them in the vignettes.

AFAIK the suggested way (see [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1213), [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1785) and [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2100)) for reading `.osm` data into R using `sf` is 1) transform the `.osm` data into `.gpkg` format (you can use `sf::gdal_utils`) and 2) read the .gpkg file. If you can share the .osm file I can check it from my laptop.

The error that you show in the OP is mentioned [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html) and if you can share the `.osm` file I can test reading it.

Comment: Can you imagine, why none of the shell commands works? I need to do it manually...

Comment: You mean `shell("7z e muenchen.osm.gz")`? Are you using windows?

Comment: Yes, sorry - a typo... I corrected my Edit. And yes, I am on Windows.

Comment: I think that you should only add "7z" to the windows path. I followed the instructions [here](https://help.goodsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007773451-Automated-Backup-with-Compression-and-Encryption)

Comment: Strange problem. Thanks a lot. In case this is a new question - it still does not work...

Comment: Great!!! `R.utils::gunzip(filename = "muenchen.osm.gz")` works :-) Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure how it works on SO but If you are still interested in the topic I edited the answer and sent you a message on chat.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! Great book - I didn't know that! ... I need to read first. In case of questions, I'll provide a link ;-)

Comment: If you are interested, have a look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/363307/121504) ;-)